# restkit should not map an attribute in entity

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mapping, restkit

I have an `entity Artist.` I get all my artists from a webservice using `Restkit`. The entity has some attributes.

```
 1. art_id
 2. art_name
 3. art_stage
 4. ...
```

Now all those values i am getting back from the webservice and mapped them correctly. 
But now I want to make a favorite list. The user can tick artists to favorise them. So I've added an `attribute`art_favo to my entity. This is just a `0 or 1`.

When I run the app and I tick an artist to favorise him, it works. The artist get favorised.

But now the problem I am having is that when I run again. `Restkit` is gonna map again all the artists. But also setting the art_favo attribute for every artist back to 0.

My question is know how can I say to Restkit that is should ignore that attribute in the mapping?

**Edit mapping of artists**

```
  RKEntityMapping* artistMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Artists" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
    artistMapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"art_id"] ;
    [artistMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"id": @"art_id",
     @"name": @"art_name",
     @"bodyN1": @"art_body",
     @"stageId": @"art_stageid",
     @"day": @"art_day",
     @"timeStart": @"art_timestart",
     @"edition": @"art_timestop",
     @"image":@"art_image",
     @"art_edition": @"art_edition"

     }];
   RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor2 = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:artistMapping
                                                                                        pathPattern:nil
                                                                                            keyPath:@"data.artists"                                                                                       statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];
```

Comment: Each time you need to call web service?

Comment: Every time my app starts up it is gonna check if there are changes. But because I not getting back art_favo from my webservice it is gonna set that value to 0

Comment: Have you verified that result or you're guessing? RestKit will only set values it knows about, so it won't change an existing fav art_favo setting. The question is: is RestKit creating all new items or updating existing items. I guess this is CoreData, do the entities have a unique identifier?

Comment: @wain they are updating existing items. and the entities got a unique identifier (art_id)

Comment: Have you set: 'mapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"art_id" ];' ?

Comment: @Wain I've updated my question with the code of the artist mapping.

Comment: I trust you're saving the managed object context after every change to the favourites setting?

Comment: Yes I'm doing it like this: NSError *error = nil;
    // Save the object to persistent store
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Can't Save! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
    }